# Relationally assigning user-voted tags to items

Tags: mysql, relationship, rdbms

I'm creating a site containing thousands of items. Among other things, users can vote to assign tags to items with the following logic:

1. Users can vote on any number of tags for every item.
2. The items can have any number of tags.
3. Any item gains the tag where `[the number of votes for that tag] ≥ 0.5 * [the number of votes for the most voted tag]` (within the question).
4. Users can see and alter their vote for an item - so I need to save the actual votes.

I'm new to SQL and am wondering how to best populate the items with the tags.

I want the relationship to be accessible both ways. I.e., I want to be able to get all `tags` for any `item` *and* all `items` for any `tag`.

The tech stack is:

- DB: a MySQL-server running v. 8 (can switch to e.g. Postgres)
- API: a node app running express with Objection.js as the ORM (but I suppose the question is quite API-agnostic).

I can see two principal methods of doing it:

**Solution 1**: When querying for the item or tag, count and group the votes and select the ones that meet the criteria in point 3 above.

**Solution 2**: When users vote, do the same calculations and save the tags in a junction table.

As far as I can see, a MWE setup of the database is with the following 4 tables:

```
user TABLE
- id
- (...)


question TABLE
- id
- (...)


tag TABLE
- id
- (...)

votes TABLE
- user_id
- question_id
- tag_id
```

and if solution 2 is chosen, a 5th table is added:

```
question_tag TABLE
- question_id
- tag_id
```

I've managed to get both setups working during development.

For solution 1, I like how there is no data redundancy. However, the relationship is less directly defined, and querying for the "other" data is a bit messy - and have to be so both ways.

For solution 2, I (essentially) store the same data twice. However, the relationship query is much simpler and probably more performant (I'm expecting many more simple views of both items and tags than votes).

So, essentially my question boils down to: Which is considered better practice - and is there an even better way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see that option 2 offers much advantage over option 1. Option 1 with DISTINCT would achieve the same thing. But if I'm wrong (performancewise), it would be simple enough to prove.